# Format Members property in Get-ADGroup

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a following PowerShell command, which works good for me, gives me the result I need (details about AD groups and their members)

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase "CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com" | 
    Select-Object -Property Name, Description, GroupCategory, Members | 
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

But I would like to format `Members` property to just show the `DisplayName` of the user, not his entire LDAP Path.

The output of the Members property is:

```
{CN=John Doe,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com, CN=Jane Doe,CN=Users, DC=domain, DC=com,...}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a Calculated property to add a custom chunk of code which PowerShell will execute to calculate the value of a particular property.

To start, we know we can select just the name of users of a group with this code:

```
 get-adgroupmember 'Domain Admins'| select Name
```

Now, we can embed this within our previous Select-Object command like so:

```
RegularProperty1,RegularProperty2,@{Name='Column Heading';Expression={<code to run>}}
```

To add this into your original select statement:

```
Name, Description, GroupCategory, @{Name='Members';exp={Get-adgroupmember $_.Name | Select -expand Name}}
```

The finished result looks like this:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties * | 
   Select-Object -Property Name, Description, GroupCategory,`
  @{Name='Members';exp={Get-adgroupmember $_.Name | Select -expand Name}}  | 
       Format-Table -AutoSize
```

[image]

Comment: Couldn't figure it out completely, thanks :-) It seems easier using `Get-ADGroupMember` than `Get-ADUser`.

Comment: I would _highly_ suggest you update the code when it comes to `-Properties *` I know you just copied it from the OP but there should be no reason to pull _all_ properties. You even know which ones are needed.

Comment: Thanks @FoxDeploy, that did the trick. When I export it into CSV, I lose the commas and {} brackets, how can I preserve commas, just not to have the list like `user1 user2 user3` Doesn't matter that much if it's pain in the ass.
@Matt Were you thinking of just doing the following `Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties Name, Description, GroupCategory, Members | 
   Select-Object ...` just because I will do "work" only on those properties? Thanks to both!

Comment: yeah, you can lose the brackets.  Change the calculated property to look like this:  @{Name='Members';exp={(Get-adgroupmember $_.Name | Select -expand Name) -join ','}}